# PHP to Insert Empty Months into foreach loop

Tags: php, graph, foreach

I have am using MySQL to generate data for a graph. The graph needs to include the months that have past during the current year. For Example: Today is July so the graph should include January-July. The SQL data does not have numbers for each month.

Here is my SQL Output:

```
Units_Counted           Date 
    607                   2
    2120                  5
    42                    7
```

The "date" field is the month.
When I print it to the graph I need it to look like this.

```
Units_Counted           Date
    0                     1
    607                   2
    0                     3
    0                     4
    2120                  5
    0                     6
    42                    7
```

Here is my current PHP code. I need to add another loop in here but I cant seem to get it right.

```
$Month = 1;
foreach ($stmtIndividualGraphDatarows as $stmtIndividualGraphDatarow){
    if ($stmtIndividualGraphDatarow['GraphMonth'] == $Month)
        {
        echo "{";
            echo "'x': '".$stmtIndividualGraphDatarow['GraphMonth']."',";
            echo "'y':".$stmtIndividualGraphDatarow['GraphCounts'];
        echo "},";
        }
    else {
        echo "{";
            echo "'x': '".$Month."',";
            echo "'y': 0";
        echo "},";}
        $Month++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope my code will be helpful:

```
 <?php
 $list = array(
     array(
         'GraphMonth' => 2,
         'GraphCounts' => 607,
     ),
     array(
         'GraphMonth' => 5,
         'GraphCounts' => 2120,
     ),
     array(
         'GraphMonth' => 7,
         'GraphCounts' => 42,
     ),
 );
 $max = 0;

 $month_count = array();
 foreach ($list as $item)
 {
     $month = $item['GraphMonth'];
     $count = $item['GraphCounts'];
     if ($month > $max)
     {
         $max = $month;
     }
     $month_count[$month] = $count;
 }

 for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++)
 {
     $month = $i;
     $count = 0;
     if (isset($month_count[$i]))
     {
         $count = $month_count[$i];
     }
     $msg = "{'x': '$month', 'y': '$count'}";
     echo $msg, "\n";
 }
 // output:
 //{'x': '1', 'y': '0'}
 //{'x': '2', 'y': '607'}
 //{'x': '3', 'y': '0'}
 //{'x': '4', 'y': '0'}
 //{'x': '5', 'y': '2120'}
 //{'x': '6', 'y': '0'}
 //{'x': '7', 'y': '42'}
```

Comment: I already stored the data in an array. Is there a way to incorporate that rather than pulling it all out and doing it again?

Comment: You mean like the way you did that?